# Error with JPA PagingAndSorting request parameter

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a Controller that pages and sorts all the news in my database:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/viewstatus", method = RequestMethod.GET)
ModelAndView viewStatus(ModelAndView modelAndView, @RequestParam(name = "p", defaultValue = "1") int pageNumber) {

    Page<StatusUpdate> page = statusUpdateService.getPage(pageNumber);
modelAndView.getModel().put("page", page);

    modelAndView.setViewName("app.viewStatus");

    return modelAndView;
}
```

With its call to the service that works fine:

```
public Page<StatusUpdate> getPage(int pageNumber) {
    PageRequest request = new PageRequest(pageNumber-1, pageSize, Sort.Direction.DESC, "added");
    
    return statusUpdateDao.findAll(request);
}
```

But now, I would like to do the same SortingAndPaging BUT with one parameter (SiteUser). Here is my object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "status_update")
public class StatusUpdate {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Size(min=5, max=255, message="{addstatus.title.size}")
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    
    @Size(min=5, max=5000, message="{addstatus.text.size}")
    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "added")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss")
    private Date added;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = SiteUser.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private SiteUser siteUser;
    
    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        if (added == null) {
            added = new Date();
        }
    }
    
    public StatusUpdate() {
        
    }
```

But when I do it, it gives me this error:

```
Exception: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [3] did not match expected type [com.caveofprogramming.model.entity.SiteUser (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [3] did not match expected type [com.caveofprogramming.model.entity.SiteUser (n/a)]
        Failed URL: http://192.168.160.128:8080/viewmystatus
        Exception message: Parameter value [3] did not match expected type [com.caveofprogramming.model.entity.SiteUser (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [3] did not match expected type [com.caveofprogramming.model.entity.SiteUser (n/a)]
```

I tired to send a String, but it did not work. I had to change it to a NativeQuery but I does not work with PagingAndSorting, it only works as a List (which is a headache to work with). So if you can help me with the ERROR of PagingAndSorting that would be great.

Here is the Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/viewmystatus", method = RequestMethod.GET)
ModelAndView viewMyStatus(ModelAndView modelAndView, @RequestParam(name = "p", defaultValue = "1") int pageNumber) {

    SiteUser user = getUser();
    
    Long user_id= user.getId();
    
    Page<StatusUpdate> page = statusUpdateService.findMyStatusUpdates(user_id, pageNumber);
    
    for(StatusUpdate statusUpdate: page){
        
        SiteUser siteUser= statusUpdate.getSiteUser();
        
        modelAndView.getModel().put("siteuser", siteUser);
    }
    
    modelAndView.getModel().put("page", page);

    modelAndView.setViewName("app.viewStatus");

    return modelAndView;
}
```

Here is the service:

```
public Page<StatusUpdate> findMyStatusUpdates(Long user_id, int pageNumber) {
    PageRequest request = new PageRequest(pageNumber-1, pageSize, Sort.Direction.DESC, "added"); 
    
    return statusUpdateDao.findBySiteUser(user_id, request);
}
```

And the DAO:

```
@Repository
public interface StatusUpdateDao extends PagingAndSortingRepository<StatusUpdate, Long> {
    StatusUpdate findFirstByOrderByAddedDesc();
    
    Page<StatusUpdate> findBySiteUser(Long user_id, Pageable pageable);
    
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `SiteUser` object:

```
public Page<StatusUpdate> findMyStatusUpdates(Long user_id, int pageNumber) {
    PageRequest request = new PageRequest(pageNumber-1, pageSize, Sort.Direction.DESC, "added"); 

    return statusUpdateDao.findBySiteUser(new SiteUser(user_id), request);
}
```

You could try query by nested properties as well, but I think you must change `user_id` by `userId`, as underscore is a reserved character. Have a look to the documentation:

[Spring data JPA Property expressions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)

---

Have you changed your `findBySiteUser` method? The one you posted looks fine but it seems is complaining about the signature. Even when `PageRequest` implements `Pageable` the signature has to be declared, explicitly, using `Pageable`, but the error message you are getting says `PageRequest`

```
public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.caveofprogramming.model.repository.StatusUpdateDao.findB‌​ySiteUser(com.caveof‌​programming.model.en‌​tity.SiteUser,org.sp‌​ringframework.data.d‌​omain.PageRequest)
```

More info:

[PageRequest parameter not recognized as Pageable in Paging query](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-865)

Comment: It does not work. It gives me an error: ..... Could not autowire field: ..: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.caveofprogramming.model.repository.StatusUpdateDao.findBySiteUser(com.caveofprogramming.model.entity.SiteUser,org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest)

Comment: It works. I passed the SiteUser to the DAO: Page<StatusUpdate> findBySiteUser(SiteUser user, Pageable pageable);